# Using Spark filter a data frame with conditions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame which looks like

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("User 1","X"), ("User 2", "Y"), ("User 3", "X"), ("User 2", "E"), ("User 3", "E"))).toDF("user", "event")

scala> df.show
+------+-----+
|  user|event|
+------+-----+
|User 1|    X|
|User 2|    Y|
|User 3|    X|
|User 2|    E|
|User 3|    E|
+------+-----+
```

I want to find all the users who has event "X" but don't have event "E"

In this case only 'User 1' qualifies as it does not have an event "E" entry. How can I do it using Spark API?

Comment: create 2 df of X and E and join them using not equal to condition

Answer (score 4):

Left join can be used:

```
val xDF = df.filter(col("event") === "X")
val eDF = df.filter(col("event") === "E")
val result = xDF.as("x").join(eDF.as("e"), List("user"), "left_outer").where(col("e.event").isNull).select(col("x.user"))
```

Result is:

```
+------+
|user  |
+------+
|User 1|
+------+
```

Comment: Join is expensive.

Answer (score 4):

You can group users with collection of events and then filter out events for appropriate user based on specific condition.

```
val result = df.groupBy("user")
    .agg(collect_list("event")
    .as("events"))
    .filter( p => p.getList(1).contains("X") && !p.getList(1).contains("E"))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
val tmp = df.groupBy("user").pivot("event").count
tmp.show
+------+----+----+----+
|  user|   E|   X|   Y|
+------+----+----+----+
|User 2|   1|null|   1|
|User 3|   1|   1|null|
|User 1|null|   1|null|
+------+----+----+----+
tmp.filter(  ($"X" isNotNull) and ($"E" isNull) ).show
+------+----+---+----+
|  user|   E|  X|   Y|
+------+----+---+----+
|User 1|null|  1|null|
+------+----+---+----+
tmp.filter(  ($"X" isNotNull) and ($"E" isNull) ).select("user","X").show 
+------+---+
|  user|  X|
+------+---+
|User 1|  1|
+------+---+
```

And hope this will help

Comment: tmp.filter(  ($"X" isNotNull) and ($"E" isNull) ).select("user","X").show has been added ! Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can count rows of each users and count each rows of users and events and the filter those rows whose both counts are equal and event column has X value.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
df.withColumn("count", count($"user").over(Window.partitionBy("user")))
    .withColumn("distinctCount", count($"user").over(Window.partitionBy("user", "event")))
    .filter($"count" === $"distinctCount" && $"event" === "X")
    .drop("count", "distinctCount")
```

You should get the result you want

I hope the answer is helpful